# Angularjs : Controller Function : variables : 'var' or controller propeties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS application inside a function which is again inside a Controller, 
what will be best approach while creating a variable.

- normally create with `var` keyword

  ```
      function getAnswer() {
         //Some code here
         var persistedDateValue = templateFactory.getAnswer(ctrl.item.ItemId);
        //Some other code here
        return persistedDateValue;
     }
  ```
- add it to the controller scope

  ```
      function getDateAnswer() {
      //Some code here
      ctrl.persistedDateValue = templateFactory.getAnswer(ctrl.item.ItemId);
      //Some other code here
      return ctrl.persistedDateValue;
  }
  ```

Here `ctrl` is controller , like in Directive `controllerAs: 'ctrl',`.

My understating is that option one is better as we do not need this variable other then this function.

Please suggest.

Comment: You should be binding to `this` in the controller

Comment: It depends on if you need to test it or not. If it's private, just create a variable, if you need outside access, make it a controller property.

Comment: @SimonH , if I understand you correctly , I have this inside my controller : `var ctrl = this`;

Comment: Please specify the reason for DownVote ?

Comment: yes, why downvote ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is very permissive on this. If you were using a more strict language as C or any of it's variations you couldn't do what you expose in the second option.
This way of accessing variables form an outer scope (from outside the function) is called "closure" and could be helpful in some situations, but for sure not in the one you're exposing, that would only mess your code, since the function itself can return it's results by it's result stament in a "normal" fashion, maintaining one of the most important principles of the programming science: Separation of Concerns (SoC for friends)

So stick to option 1

Comment: With option#1,will it create a new variable every time the call goes into getDateAnswer() and does not destroy it. If we use the controller scope, will it reuses the same memory.

Comment: The memory used by the variable should be marked as releaseable as soon as the function call is complete, so that shoudn't worry you. But, if these variables are very big, and the function is called a lot of times in a loop or so, and you're concerned about micro-optimization, then it would make sense to use a closure here. Both options could be correct, you have to trade between performance and code clarity, depending of what it makes more sense in the context of your program.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ZSnake's answer, but if you do need to make this variable available in the rest of your controller on on the view then you will need

```
.controler('ControllerName', function() {
   var _this = this;

   function getDateAnswer() {
     //Some code here
     _this.persistedDateValue = templateFactory.getAnswer(ctrl.item.ItemId);
   }
```

Comment: With option#1,will it create a new variable every time the call goes into getDateAnswer() and does not destroy it. If we use the controller scope, will it reuses the same memory.

Comment: No, this will mutate `_this.persistedDataValue` which is a single value in the controller itself

Comment: sorry, I am making to long discussion; but `var persistedDateValue` create new variable every time is not it ?   considering the tread-off between creating new variable and mutate variable , which one is more preferable considering performance .

Comment: A var inside a function will get lost after the function terminates. If you only need the value transiently then return the value and use it up in the controller. If you want to persist you can so it my way or as zsnake suggests. No great difference

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be option 1, if, as you said, you're not going to use that variable elsewhere. That way you avoid having unused data on your scope.